# how to access to LinqToSqlcCasses from another application

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

i want to have access to LinqToSqlClasses (mydbDataContext) class from another solution project. in fact, i can make an instanse of this class, but cant access to methods like SubmitChanges() and so on. please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you referenced `System.Data.Linq` in the project that references your Linq2SQL classes?

Comment: if you means is System.Linq yes but i havent System.Data.Linq reference.